# Bug or Feature: Kotlin allows to change 'val' to 'var' in inheritance

Tags: inheritance, side-effects, kotlin

I just started to explore the language Kotlin. I'm struggling with inheritance, var&val and side-effects.

If I declare a trait `A` with a `val x` and override `x` in `AImpl` it is possible to override it as `var` (see code below). Surprisingly the `print()` method in `A` is affected by the reassignment of `x` even though `x` is a value in `A`. Is this a bug or a feature?

Code:

```
trait A {
  fun print() {
    println("A.x = $x")
  }

  val x : Int;
}

class AImpl(x : Int) : A {
  override var x = x; // seems like x can be overriden as `var`
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  val a = AImpl(2)

  a.print() // A.x = 2

  a.x = 3; // x can be changed

  // even though print() is defined in trait A
  // where x is val it prints x = 3
  a.print() // A.x = 3

}
```

I'm aware of the fact that if I define `a` with type `A` explicitly it is not allowed to change `x`:

```
val a = AImpl(2) : A
a.x = 3 // ERROR: value x cannot be reassigned
```

But as the first case shows, inheritance can cause side effects which are clearly not intended in `A`. How do I protect values from being changed by inheritance?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can make your `val` `final`, i.e. forbid overriding it at all. 
If you define a `val` in a class, it is `final` by default.

Also, if you need to override a `val` with a `var`, but do not want the setter to be public, you can say so:

```
override var x = 1
    private set
```

Overriding a `val` with a `var` **is a feature**. It is equivalent to adding a set-method while in the superclass there was only a get-method. And this is rather important in implementing some patterns, such as read-only interfaces.

There's no way to "protect" your `val` from being overridden in a way that allows changing mutation other than making it `final`, because `val` does not mean "immutable reference", but merely "read-only property". In other words, when your trait `A` declares a `val`, it means that **through a reference of type `A`** the client can not write this `val`, no other guarantees intended, or indeed possible.

P.S. Semicolons are optional in Kotlin, feel free to omit them altogether

Answer (score 3):

I would consider this a feature, as changing val to var imposes weaker usage restrictions and **can't break any superclass code**. Similar situation can be observed with visibility modifiers:

```
trait A {
  protected fun print() {
    ...
  }
}

class AImpl: A {
  public override fun print() {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this example visibility restrictions are also relaxed by a subclass, although some people are considering this technique as an antipattern.

> How do I protect values from being changed by inheritance?

In kotlin you can explicitly define if any particular class member can be overriden by a subclass using `open` modifier. In traits, however, all the members are open by default. The solution is to replace trait with class, so you'll be able to control inheritance:

```
abstract class A {
  fun print() {
    ...
  }

  val x : Int = 2;
}

class AImpl(x : Int) : A() {
  override var x = x // compilation error
}
```